# Windows XP/7/8 software installation automation

Tags: windows, installation, automation

I'm a computer technician and I install 5+ windows computers a day. I have no problem with the installation of windows and the drivers as I use DriverPack Solution.
The only problem is that I install 10+ default software  (chrome, firefox, vlc, winrar....)
I want to make this process done automatically with one click. I found WPI Wizard but I got some problems with it.
So I want a piece of free software that:
- Installs a list of pre-downloaded software (not to download on the fly)
- make custom pre-configured install (chose weather to install toolbars that come with some software)
- automatically put the serial number if any

Thanks

Comment: http://ninite.com/ downloads on the fly, but it's worth a try. Or you could create yourself a custom Windows image and then install it on each machine.

Comment: Why not install via silent commands from setupcomplete.cmd with apps in the $OEM$ folder.  That's basically what WPI does sans the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, I'll be curious to hear what other users offer.  Here's what I'd do...

1. Use Sysprep to create an image with as much software as you can, then using WinPE you can deploy images quickly and easily.  I use this at work every week (not 5 times a day, but we're getting there), and it works really well.
2. Use a powershell script to install software.  Below is an example of a small portion of our script:
3. Check out chocolately.  Its a relatively new program that creates a package management system for Windows.  Install firefox is as simple as running `cinst firefox`.  Where "cinst" is chocolatey install.

You can use any combination of these soultions as well.  Some programs might be easier installed with Chocolatey, while others might be easier done with a batch script.

```
START /d "C:\IT\install" /WAIT Firefox_Setup_19.0.2.exe  
ECHO Firefox is now installed.
```

Comment: You should `start /wait` so that it doesn't start installing the next item before firefox finishes.